# Modify passed parameter directly

Tags: bash, obfuscation

I have following function:

```
s() { c=$1; while((c--)) ; do printf 'x' ; done }; s 2
```

So `x` is printed two times.

Is it possible to simplify this code ?

At first I'd like to skip assignation part `c=$1;` and do:

```
while((1--))
```

Do you have any ideas ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
s() { for i; do printf 'x' ; done }; s 2 3
```

Here the `for` loop takes by default the arguments passed to the function and assigns them to i, so you don't need `c=$1` anymore.

Ok, I haven't answered your problem directly.

To modify parameters, you must use **`set -- word`**, for example:

```
> set -- 5
> echo $1
5
> set -- $(( $1-1 ))
> echo $1
4
```

Your function will be :

```
s() { while (( $1 )); do echo 'x'; set -- $(( ${1}-1 )); done }
```

But you will lose a little performance and clarity in the script :

```
>time s 100000 > /dev/null
real    0m1.235s
user    0m1.196s
sys     0m0.040s
```

While with `s() { c=$1; while (( c-- )); do echo 'x'; done }`:

```
>time s 100000 > /dev/null
real    0m0.520s
user    0m0.496s
sys     0m0.024s
```

I have tried this one :

```
s1() { for i in $(eval echo {1..${1}}); do printf 'x'; done }
```

But the main problem is the creation of a child process for the `eval` statement. The performance is a little faster than above, but still a little difficult to read:

```
>time s1 100000 > /dev/null
real    0m0.453s
user    0m0.412s
sys     0m0.040s
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: But if I's like to pring `x` 10 times, I have call `s` function with `2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10` arguments ?